# Setting up an SSH Key and

Tags: github, ssh-keys

I am new to coding and have been tasked with setting up a new SSH Key and connecting to GitHub. I have followed all the steps, and when I check if I have successfully paired I get this message:

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com
The authenticity of host 'github.com (140.82.121.4)' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:+DiY3wvvV6TuJJhbpZisF/zLDA0zPMSvHdkr4UvCOqU.
This key is not known by any other names
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
Hi indiataylor1! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction ?

Have tried creating a new SSH Key and starting from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

You are good to go.

The "ED25519 key fingerprint" message is seen only at the first SSH connection, and yours does match the [official GitHub ones](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-01-18-githubs-ssh-host-keys-are-now-published-in-the-api/).

If you try again `ssh -T git@github.com`, you will only see:

```
Hi indiataylor1! 
You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

From there, start cloning your repository with:

```
git clone git@github.com:You/yourRepository
```

Comment: @indiataylor Did it work? It yes, great, well done!